# Scala and forward references

Tags: scala, reference, compilation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Scala: forward references - why does this code compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762838/scala-forward-references-why-does-this-code-compile)

```
object Omg {

  class A

  class B(val a: A)

  private val b = new B(a)

  private val a = new A

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println(b.a)
  }

}
```

the following code prints "null". In java. similar construction doesn't compile because of invalid forward reference. The question is - why does it compile well in Scala? Is that by design, described in SLS or simply bug in 2.9.1?

Comment: The issue that annoys me about this is that it allows a val to change its value. That makes me sad :-(

Comment: it's a bit strange - lots of error could be caused by that, and I relied on Java behavior, which requires to have values initialized before they are used.

Comment: @jdevelop Even java doesn't catch all possible forward references.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral but this case if obvious.

Comment: I ran into this same problem with package objects.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It's not a bug, but a classic error when learning Scala. When the object `Omg` is initialized, all values are first set to the default value (`null` in this case) and then the constructor (i.e. the object body) runs.

To make it work, just add the `lazy` keyword in front of the declaration you are forward referencing (value `a` in this case):

```
object Omg {

  class A

  class B(val a: A)

  private val b = new B(a)

  private lazy val a = new A

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println(b.a)
  }
}
```

Value `a` will then be initialized on demand.

This construction is fast (the values are only initialized once for all application runtime) and thread-safe.

Comment: Adding `lazy` works if you *know* you are executing the statements in the wrong order. But if you *think* you have them in the correct order, you probably won't think of adding that "unnecessary" `lazy`. :/

Answer (score 8):

The way that I understand it, this has to do with how the Scala classes are created. In Java, the class defined above would be initializing the variables inline, and since `a` had not been defined yet, it could not be compiled. However, in Scala it is more the equivalent of this in Java (which should also produce null in the same scenario):

```
class Omg {
  private B b = null;
  private A a = null;

  Omg(){ 
    b = new B(a);
    a = new A();
  }
}
```

Alternately, you could make your declaration of `b` lazy, which would defer setting the value until it is called (at which time a will have been set).

Answer (score 6):

If this is a concern, compile with `-Xcheckinit` during development and iterate until the exceptions go away.

Spec 5.1 for template body statements executed in order; beginning of 4.0 for forward references in blocks.

[Forward References - why does this code compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762838/scala-forward-references-why-does-this-code-compile)

Answer (score 3):

As @paradigmatic states, it's not really a bug. It's the initialization order, which follows the declaration order. It this case, `a` is null when `b` is declared/init-ed.

Changing the line `private val b = new B(a)` to `private lazy val b = new B(a)` will fix  issue, since using lazy will delay the init. of b to it's first usage.

It's very likely that this behavior is described in the SLS.