# Why is using uninitialized variables allowed in Scala?

Tags: scala, jvm, forward-reference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Forward References - why does this code compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762838/scala-forward-references-why-does-this-code-compile)
>   [Scala and forward references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184997/scala-and-forward-references)

```
object Main extends App {
  val a = 4
  val b = a + c
  val c = 5
  println(b) // => 4
}
```

This will print **4** as `c` apparently is `0` when `b` is assigned. `a` and `c` are values, so they should not be `0` in one moment, and `5` in the next. In Scala, they should be **immutable**, right?

Shouldn't I at least get some sort of warning? Of course, in the example above, you have to be an idiot to miss *that*, but in more complicated cases, it can be hard to tell what order to put it.

I am of course aware that I can use `lazy val b = ...` but what if I *think* I've put it in the right order, when I really haven't. Isn't it dangerous as hell not getting any warning at all on this? This runs just fine!? How does this get passed *both* Scala IDE *and* the compiler? Is it on purpose? Or is it a bug that cannot be fixed? :/

:)

Comment: These should answer the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184997/scala-and-forward-references and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504809/scala-strange-behavior-in-class-object-initialization/13504969#13504969

Comment: @jcern : That thread explains why it *happens*, but not *why* it is allowed by *design*. Why is this dangerous behavior not being fixed / not on the SIPs? A link to comment/blog post from one of the Scala designers would be awesome here :)

Comment: @kornfridge see [this thread](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/scala-Initialization-Order-td1999887.html). In short: nobody come up with an idea on such compilation scheme which will satisfactory solve this problem (from many points of view: speed, compability, etc).