# How to run a scala program in terminal on mac?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization, deserialization

I built an object which is supposed to serialize and deserialize a file. I built it in scala in terminal on mac. I'm new to scala and don't have that much programming experience in general. I was wondering how I could run the object so that it performs the task I assigned it to do. Might be a dumb question but I don't know what to do. [Here's an image of what my object is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2Dpb.png)

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter in terminal ([repl](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/repl/overview.html))

```
serializationTest3.main(Array())
```

"Running" an object is actually executing the method `main(Array[String]): Unit` of the object.

Extending trait `App`

```
object X extends App {
  foo()
}
```

is like wrapping the object body with method `main`

```
object X {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    foo()
  }
}
```

https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.3/scala/App.html

[How Scala App trait and main works internally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53468358/how-scala-app-trait-and-main-works-internally)

[Difference between object with main() and extends App in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14553461/difference-between-object-with-main-and-extends-app-in-scala)

[Difference between using App trait and main method in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667630/difference-between-using-app-trait-and-main-method-in-scala)